# syncfusion_flutter_gauges secondaryContainer error

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

when I add `syncfusion_flutter_gauges` Library I get the `secondaryContainer` error.
My Flutter version is `2.5.2` I checked similar questions for the answers but it didn't work
I don't want to upgrade my Flutter version

```
/C:/flutter%202.5.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_gauges-19.4.55/lib/src/radial_gauge/pointers/marker_pointer_renderer.dart:631:34: Error: The getter 'secondaryContainer' isn't defined for the class 'ColorScheme'.
- 'ColorScheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/color_scheme.dart' ('/C:/flutter%202.5.2/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart').
package:flutter/…/material/color_scheme.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'secondaryContainer'.
```

Please Help

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to keep running with an older Flutter/Dart version, also for possible security reasons. Judging by [this issue](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-widgets/issues/592), you should be able to use version `19.4.48` of the package with your current Flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

They have upgraded their source with the latest Flutter stable channel versions. So this issue occurs at your end. If you wish to use the Flutter SDK version 2.5.2, you can use the [Flutter Gauge - 19.4.48](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges/versions/19.4.48) version to resolve this issue. The latest Flutter Gauge version is compatible with the latest Flutter stable versions.